# Contact Form 7 - Sum validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, sum, field

I’m trying to insert an error message whether the sum of some input fields is greater than a certain number.

More specifically, the contact form is to enquire about the vacancy of hotel room.
For each room, I need to know how many people/pets are going to be in that room.
Of course, there is a limit to it, and that is 4 people/pets.

I’d like to insert an error message anytime they try to book a room for more than 4 people/pets.

In the contact form, it would be something like:

```
<label> Adults*
[select* r1-adults "1" "2" "3" "4"] </label>
<label> Children*
[select* r1-children "0" "1" "2" "3"] </label>
<label> Babies*
[select* r1-babies "0" "1" "2" "3"] </label>
<label> Pets*
[select* r1-pets "0" "1" "2" "3"] </label>
```

In the functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_max_capacity*', 'custom_max_capacity_validation_filter', 20, 2 );

function custom_max_capacity_validation_filter( $result, $tag, $zero, $adults, $children, $babies, $pets ) {
$tag = new WPCF7_FormTag( $tag );
$zero = "0";
if ( 'r1-adults' == $tag->name AND 'r1-children' == $tag->name AND 'r1-babies' == $tag->name AND 'r1-pets' == $tag->name ) {
    $adults = isset( $_POST['r1-adults'] ) ? settype(trim( $_POST['r1-adults'] ), "integer") : settype($zero, "integer");
    $children = isset( $_POST['r1-children'] ) ? settype(trim( $_POST['r1-children'] ), "integer") : settype($zero, "integer");
    $babies = isset( $_POST['r1-babies'] ) ? settype(trim( $_POST['r1-babies'] ), "integer") : settype($zero, "integer");
    $pets = isset( $_POST['r1-pets'] ) ? settype(trim( $_POST['r1-pets'] ), "integer") : settype($zero, "integer"); 
    $sum=$adults+$children+$babies+$pets;
    if ($sum > 4 ) {
        $result->invalidate( $tag, "Max occupancy per room allowed 4 people/pets" );
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I toke the main draft from here: http://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/

However, it does not work. Indeed, I am not sure how to adapt the condition

```
if ( 'your-email-confirm' == $tag->name )
```

to my case.

Could anybody help me to fix the function? Thanks!